# Need Help in automating HTTPS Rest Calls using Selenium

Tags: java, web-services, rest, selenium, rest-assured

I'm automating **Secured HTTPs Rest calls** using **selenium**. We've java keystore file needs to be imported/added/inserted thru code. I tried many ways to send the POST request but not succeeded.
*KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("");

            ks.load(is, "password".toCharArray());*

**i'm getting the following error message.**
*Remote host closed connection during handshake


Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake*

Please help in fixing this issue.

**Used the following snippet**
#HTTPS path
String urlPath = "https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/";
String json = "";
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 0):

Generate .jks using cert and key file. then pass that .jks file in your test

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guidelines to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)